# Restrict number of lines

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I restrict the number of lines displayed in my report? I display the field `emp_desc` using this query:

```
select emp_desc from emp where emp_name in ('roger','harper','john').
```

The output of this query returns 3 rows, and each row when printed takes 2 lines -
 for a total of 6. But I want to display only 5 lines, and ignore the 6th and final line. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: All, I found that there is no way to control the number of lines at the crystal report end. So I decided to use LISTAGG function in crystal report command. But  unfortunately it does not work, it just displays a blank report. Here is the query: select (LISTAGG(emp_desc,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMP_ID) as EMP_DESC_1 from EMP where  emp_name = '{?EMP.EMP_NAME}'. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on the field who receives the query.

Right click on it > Format Object > Common > and mark the checkbox "Can grow"

you can specify the number of lines if you want too.

Comment: I have tried this, but this works for only single field (that is all the 6 lines come from a single field in the database). The output of my query can have single or multiple fields. The problem happens only in case of multiple fields. In the above example, it displays row1+row2+row3 (+ means concatenation). But I want row1+row2+ a part of row3, since displaying row3 fully would exceed the limit of 5 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Without a screenshot, or at least knowing what your data looks like when it's returned, we can only guess. But it sounds like you want to change the format of every 3rd row to be shorter. This can be accomplished with this pseudocode formula:

```
IF RECORDNUMBER MOD 3 = 2 THEN
    'Display a shortened version of your data
ELSE
    'Display your data normally
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it is not what I am looking for. The data from the row should get truncated the moment the number of lines on the report crosses 5 lines, no matter if its the 3rd row or any other row.

Comment: @satheeshv Then in addition to my answer, force a New Page After the third record on each page (The formula for that is just: `RECORDNUMBER MOD 3 = 2`)